# SP2013 CSOM - 401 Unauthorized Exception from Server - What Feature/Service is the issue

Tags: 2013, development, csom

I try to access a SharePoint 2013 Server via C# CSOM.

The only thing I do is create the `ClientContext`, set the `context.Credentials` to my `NetworkCredential`, and ask for the Web `Web web = context.Web;`.

After `context.ExecuteQuery();` I get an `401 Unauthorized` Error/Exception.

After playing around (with another server used for testing) I realized, that the problem is not due to incorrect password or incorrect credentials or even incorrect access rights (I'm Admin), but because of the server itself.

I know for sure:

- My Credentials work fine (I can login via Web Interface as well)
- The problem is from the server, not from the client
- On my test environment it works!

A small background info.

The System that gives me the error had an issue last week and went completely offline the whole last week. After a lot of time, the Admins got it back to work again.

I assume, that a feature or something on the system did not start properly after the issues, and that's why I can't access it via CSOM.

My question is:
What SharePoint Feature or other Service needs to run on a SharePoint Server, so you can access it via CSOM.

My source code:

```
ServicePointManager
.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; //used for https to work properly

string spurl = "https://my.spserver.com/sites/mysite";
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(spurl))
{
    context.Credentials =  new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

    try
    {

        Web web = context.Web;
        context.Load(web);


        context.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: "+e.Message);
    }




    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10364/http-401-unauthorized-using-the-managed-client-object-model